# adb shell dpm set-device-owner with Unity issue

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, kiosk, cosu

I am trying to make a Unity app go into kiosk mode by using COSU (Corporate Owned Single Use) functionality.

My plan was to first get things working using just Android, so I followed the tutorial offered by [Google Code Labs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cosu/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

After I got this working, my plan was to then figure out how to integrate this into my Unity project. I followed 
[this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ahGeTNUPLM) that showed how to make a plugin that can be called from Unity.

When I build my project, I try to execute the following command

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.modalvr.unityplugin/.DeviceAdminReceiver
```

However, I keep getting the following error

```
Error: Unknown admin: ComponentInfo{com.modalvr.unityplugin/com.modalvr.unityplugin.DeviceAdminReceiver}
```

I wonder if Unity is not merging the AndroidManifest.xml files together correctly.  Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file from plugin.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.modalvr.unityplugin">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <receiver
            android:name="com.modalvr.unityplugin.DeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I copied it and the classes.jar file into Unity's Assets/Plugins/Android/libs folder

I am able to successfully call functions in my plugin, so the plugin appears to be set up correctly.

For reference, this is my C# code that calls into the plugin

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LockManager : MonoBehaviour {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    private AndroidJavaObject playerActivityContext = null;
#endif

    public void SaveContext() {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        // First, obtain the current activity context
        using (var actClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer")) {
        playerActivityContext = actClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }

        var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.modalvr.unityplugin.PluginClass");
        plugin.CallStatic<bool>("setContext", playerActivityContext);
#endif
    }

    public void LockButtonClicked() {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        SaveContext();

        var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.modalvr.unityplugin.PluginClass");
        bool retVal = plugin.CallStatic<bool>("lock", 7);
#endif
    }

public void UnlockButtonClicked() {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        SaveContext();

        var plugin = new AndroidJavaClass("com.modalvr.unityplugin.PluginClass");
        bool retVal = plugin.CallStatic<bool>("unlock", 7);
#endif
    }
}
```

And this is the java class that defines those functions.

```
package com.modalvr.unityplugin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

public class PluginClass {
    private static Context context;

    public static boolean setContext(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean lock(int number) {
        Log.d("SOME TAG", "onReceive Lock");

        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        activity.startLockTask();

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean unlock(int number) {
        Log.d("SOME TAG", "onReceive Unlock");

        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        activity.stopLockTask();

        return true;
    }
}
```

It looks like Unity generates 2 XML files that it puts in Temp/StagingArea

AndroidManfist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.ModalVR.KioskPluginTest" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

and AndroidManifest-main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.ModalVR.KioskPluginTest" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
</manifest>
```

In neither of these files do I see the contents of my Android plugin AndroidManifest.xml  I guess that is the issue. Do I need to do something to make the manifest files merge?

And for completeness, here is

DeviceAdminReceiver.java

```
package com.modalvr.unityplugin;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;

/**
 * Handles events related to the managed profile.
 */
public class DeviceAdminReceiver extends android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceAdminReceiver";

    /**
     * @param context The context of the application.
     * @return The component name of this component in the given context.
     */
    public static ComponentName getComponentName(Context context) {
        return new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), DeviceAdminReceiver.class);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
John Lawrie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to do something to make the manifest files merge?

Yes.

The manifest in Unity will automatically merge **only** if you compile the Java plugin as **.aar** package. If you build it as **.jar** file then you have to manually put the Manifest in the right folder in Unity so that Unity can merge it into your program during build.

You are currently building as **.jar** library so below is where to place the Manifest:

Put the *AndroidManifest.xml* file in your `<ProjectName>Assets\Plugins\Android` folder. Make sure to spell *AndroidManifest* and the folder names of where to put it correctly. That's it.

Comment: I have updated my project to generate .aar files and now I get the files to merge properly. Thanks.